# How to read mail failure items from Outlook inbox to save them in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, email

I'm sending emails and want to read and save failed email im an excel sheet. I could read subject ,body attachments file names ..etc . I want to read only email and reolied text near the icon as shown on the attached snapshot. Code is attached if someone can help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnndK.png)

```
Sub GetInboxItems()

   Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
   Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem 'MailItem
   Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
   Dim xlWB As Object 'Excel.Workbook
   Dim xlSheet As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
   Dim Lines() As String
   Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, P As Integer
   Dim myItem As Variant
   Dim subjectOfEmail As String
   Dim bodyOfEmail As String
   Dim q

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'Try access to excel
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
   If xlApp Is Nothing Then
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     xlApp.Application.Visible = True
     If xlApp Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Excel is not accessable"
       Exit Sub
     End If
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0

    'Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    'Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

 'Add a new workbook
   Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
   xlApp.Application.Visible = True
   Set xlSheet = xlWB.ActiveSheet
   Set myFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
     subjectOfEmail = myItem.Subject
     bodyOfEmail = myItem.Body

 'Search for Undeliverable email
     If subjectOfEmail Like "*Delivery*" & "*failed*" Then
       x = x + 1
 'Extract email address from email body
       Lines = Split(myItem.Body, vbCrLf)
       For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
         P = InStr(1, Lines(i), "@", vbTextCompare)
         q = InStr(1, Lines(i), "(", vbTextCompare)
         If P > 0 Then
           xlApp.Range("A" & x) = Trim$(Mid$(Lines(i), 1, q - 1)) 'extract the email address
           Exit For
         End If
       Next
    End If
  Next

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add reference: Tolls -> References -> Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

```
Sub GetInboxItems()

Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem 'MailItem
Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
Dim Lines() As String
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, P As Integer
Dim myItem As Variant
Dim subjectOfEmail As String
Dim bodyOfEmail As String
Dim q
Dim Results As MatchCollection
Dim match_ as Match

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Try access to excel
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If xlApp Is Nothing Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Application.Visible = True

    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Excel is not accessable"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Set ol = New Outlook.Application
'Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Add a new workbook
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
Set xlSheet = xlWB.ActiveSheet
Set myFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
    subjectOfEmail = myItem.Subject

    'Search for Undeliverable email
    If subjectOfEmail Like "*Delivery*" & "*failed*" Then
        bodyOfEmail = myItem.Body

        x = x + 1
        'Extract email address from email body

        strPattern = "[a-z0-9-.+_]+@[a-z-]+\.[a-z]+"

        Set Results = RegEx(bodyOfEmail, strPattern, , True, True)

        If Not Results Is Nothing Then
            For Each match_ in Results
                cells(1,1).Value = match_
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function RegEx(strInput As String, strPattern As String, _
Optional GlobalSearch As Boolean, Optional MultiLine As Boolean, _
Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean) As MatchCollection

Dim mcolResults As MatchCollection
Dim objRegEx As New RegExp

If strPattern <> vbNullString Then

    With objRegEx
        .Global = GlobalSearch
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If objRegEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set mcolResults = objRegEx.Execute(strInput)
        Set RegEx = mcolResults
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Via https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/